# Tkinter: bind additional mouse buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to bind mouse buttons other than the left, middle, and right? For example, the side buttons on the Microsoft Intellimouse or Razer Deathadder. Some programs call them Mouse4 and Mouse5, but I tried

```
self.parent.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event:print('left'))
self.parent.bind("<Button-2>", lambda event:print('middle'))
self.parent.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event:print('right'))
self.parent.bind("<Button-4>", lambda event:print('prev'))
self.parent.bind("<Button-5>", lambda event:print('next'))
```

and only the first three work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Tkinter only supports up to the first three mouse buttons (as you have discovered). I've encountered situations where the first three are not sufficient, in which case I've found mouse buttons in combination with keys a satisfying solution. So far as I can see, the Tkinter documentation only mentions the first three buttons, and [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) website (which I use for queries such as this) makes no mention of it either. Hope that helps.

Comment: That's what I'd thought. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Tkinter is documented to support five mouse buttons, but depending on the platform, buttons 4 and 5 might be associated with the mouse wheel. 

For a definitive list of what the bind method supports, see the tk bind manual page: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for the Tkinter version 8.6 is no. Tkinter can retrieve integers for different buttons of your mouse, but binding for these details won't work.

You may print integers which equal to mouse button hits via the *Button* event type:

```
widget_variable.bind("<Button>", lambda event: print(event.num))
```

but my experiments show that these integers would not work as binding details. You may only bind all "not assigned" buttons to one handler. If you still want to handle buttons e.g. 1 and 3, this should go in the code later, and `add = "+"` should be included:

```
canvas.bind("<Button>", lambda event: print("success"))
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: None, add = "+")
canvas.bind("<Button-2>", lambda event: None)
canvas.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event: None, add = "+")
```

However on Linux-like machines *MouseWheel* event doesn't work, as it's written in the [official documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.13/TkCmd/bind.html), it is replaced by details *4* and *5*, which would bind mouse wheel scrolls down and up. So instead of:

```
canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(event.delta / 60, "units"))
```

on Windows (or similarly on MacOS), you would use details *4* and *5* for Linux:

```
canvas.bind("<Button-5>", lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units"))
canvas.bind("<Button-4>", lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units"))
```