# mouse button forward python

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm currently trying to write an Image Viewer, but the "Forward/Backward" Buttons on the mouse are not triggering any of the possible binds in tkinter.

I tried the binds:

```
<Key>, <KeyPress>, <ButtonPress>, <Return>
```

but none of them can detect the mouse clicks on the forward/backward button.

Has Python even the possiblity to detect them?

Edit:

The buttons are called XButtons and are hookable with PyHook or PyQt, but if I try to let them run in the background, they are lagging massively, any way to prevent that?

I'm currently trying to let [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428351/how-to-detect-mouse-side-buttons-with-python/25713551#25713551) run smoothly in the background without causing extreme lags

Edit:

Using wxPython with PyHook solved my problem, since Tkinter and PyHook is causing huge lags, which don't appear with wxPython

Comment: [Tkinter: bind additional mouse buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237848/tkinter-bind-additional-mouse-buttons)

Comment: found this already and was the reason why I mentioned the binds in the post, but it would suffice to trigger a callback with any lib out there, I'm not sure how it exactly works, but the forward button should at least send any signal to the frame

Answer (score 0):

The answer may vary by platform, and also by mouse driver.

On my OSX device where I have a logitech mouse with a total of five buttons, the fourth and fifth buttons are considered buttons 4 and 5. For example, I can bind to `<Button-4>` and `<Button-5>`.

That might work for you, or your mouse driver might assign those buttons to something else.

Comment: if it was the 4 and 5 key, it would've triggered by the <Button> event, tried it manually with <Button-4> and <Button-5>, but didn't work for me